# How do you tune Android's SQLite as per the SQLite docs, e.g. PRAGMA cache_size?

Tags: android, sqlite

The SQLite docs here http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#pragmas look interesting. Is there a way to try what it suggests in Android?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

> The PRAGMA statement is an SQL extension specific to SQLite and used to modify the operation of the SQLite library or to query the SQLite library for internal (non-table) data. The PRAGMA statement is issued using the same interface as other SQLite commands (e.g. SELECT, INSERT)

So, I would expect `execSQL()` on a `SQLiteDatabase` should work with a `PRAGMA` that returns no result set.

If the `PRAGMA` affects compilation of a SQLite statement, try `compileStatement()` with a `SQLiteDatabase` and see if that works. I would expect that to map to `sqlite3_prepare()` in the SQLite C API, though I am not certain of that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how in Android, it may not allow to bind parameters when using **PRAGMA** so I've to execute whole statement with parameters in it like this example:

```
"PRAGMA main.locking_mode = exclusive";
```

Maybe in Android it can be used with that `execSQL()` method only.